# How google drive, dropbox store exe files and all these unsecure files? Is not it dangerous?

Tags: sql, file, security, pdo, google-cloud-storage

I want to learn that how google drive and dropbox store exe files, is not it dangerous because I can run exe file in their server is not it?

How they handle that?

Answer (score 1):

The `.exe` file pose no harm until it is executed by some means
And to avoid execution the files are usually compressed and saved in `CDN`

> is not it dangerous?

EXE file in CDNs does not get the required environment for execution.
It's just like a PHP file in MS-DOS

**But point to be noted here is it is dangerous if you download the EXE file from the Dropbox etc and execute it in your computer**

Preferably use VirusTotal to scan before executing

Answer (score 1):

In general, storing files is not dangerous. Only executing them is.

Dropbox and Google drive do not provide any mechanism for files to be executed on their server.

A side-case to this is [XSS (Cross Site Scripting)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). That is, an HTML document could be uploaded to such a service that allows code execution on the viewing users machine, albeit in JavaScript. This could allow redirections to a malicious site though, or the opening of a dialog box asking for the user's cloud username and password. To this end, [Dropbox are ending support for the sharing of HTML documents](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Manage-account/Discontinuing-rendering-of-HTML-content/td-p/187920).

So in short, if you allow file uploads to your service, do not store the files in a a place where execution is permitted (whether that be the server itself or the user's browser).

Comment: There days they store the files in *-usercontent etc
So XSS will be executed in the scope of let's say googe-usercontent.com rather than google.com.

Comment: Even so, malicious redirects and displaying login boxes would still apply. Many non technical users would not not know the difference between the user content domain and the main domain.